# Multiple uploaded file with php with foreach function

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Now im working on multiple file uploaded with `Codeigniter`

any one can help me? because when i'm uploading my file just single file readed.

```
foreach ($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'] as $f => $tmp_name) {

        //in here just single file can readed
}
```

and this is the html code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"
action="<?php echo site_url('rooms/edit_photo/' . $room_id); ?>" method="post"
onsubmit="return AIM.submit(this, {'onStart' : startCallback, 'onComplete' : completeCallback})">
    <p><label id="upload_photo"
    for="new_photo"><?php echo translate("Upload photo"); ?></label>
    <input name="userfile[]" size="24" type="file" multiple/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button name="update_photo" class="button1" type="submit">
    <span><span><?php echo translate("Upload"); ?></span></span></button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: i think this would be help [link1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php). [link2](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to see what's currently in the `$_FILES` variable. You can do this with `print_r($_FILES)` or `var_dump($_FILES)`

Looks to me that this should be an array, so you're data is probably in this format:

```
// for the first picture    
$_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][0]
```

Furthermore: do you know CodeIgniter supplies a uploads library? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html